# Дочерные элементы в div

Tags: javascript, html

Есть список

```
<div class="top_block_portf">
   <div class="ih-item"></div>
   <div class="ih-item"></div>
   <div class="ih-item"></div>
   <div class="ih-item"></div>
</div>
```

который я обворачиваю в div с класом new1 если .ih-item больше n. получаю такой код -

```
 <div class="top_block_portf">
   <div class="new1">
     <div class="ih-item"></div>
     <div class="ih-item"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="new1">
     <div class="ih-item"></div>
     <div class="ih-item"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

а потом для первого .ih-item в блоке .new1 добавляю класс - first.

На практике выходит что только до первого .ih-item в первом блоке я добавляю класс . first

```
var quality = n;

function portfolioBlock() {
  var divs = $(".ih-item");
  for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=quality) {
    divs.slice(i, i+quality).wrapAll("<div class='new1'></div>");
  }
  var newBl = $(".new1");
  var new1 = new Array;
  newBl.each( function( index) {
    blockPort();
  });
};

function blockPort() {
  var arrDiv = new Array;
  var arrDiv= $('.new1').find('.ih-item');
    arrDiv[0].classList.add("first");
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение, может кому пригодится -

```
  var quality = 27;

function portfolioBlock() {
  var divs = $(".ih-item");
  for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=quality) {
    divs.slice(i, i+quality).wrapAll("<div class='new1'></div>");
  }
  var newBl = $(".new1");
  var new1 = new Array;
  newBl.each( function( index, el) {
    blockPort(el);
  });
  console.log(newBl);
};

function blockPort(el) {
  var arrDiv = $('.ih-item', el);
    arrDiv[0].classList.add("first");
    arrDiv[14].classList.add("second");
    arrDiv[26].classList.add("next");
  console.log(arrDiv);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Дак всё логично - вы берете первый блок `.new1` и в нём ищете `.ih-item`
Чтобы найти все первые `.ih-item` в блоках `.new1` используйте

```
$('.new1 .ih-item:first-child')
```

а затем уже с помощью `.each()` добавляйте им нужный вам класс.
С другой стороны, если это нужно только для того чтоб какие-то стили применить - дак и используйте тогда селектор `.new1 .ih-item:first-child`

Comment: когда я выведу console.log(arrDiv); там покажет что выбрано 4 блока а мне нужно чтоб код обробатывал каждый .new1 особно.

Comment: тогда нужна конструкция `$('.new1').each(function(){$('.ih-item')[0].addClass('first')});`